# Plot negative values on a log scale

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am doing some analysis to calculate the value of `log_10(x)` which is a negative number. I am now trying to plot these values, however, since the range of the answers is very large I would like to use a logarithmic scale for this. If I simply use `plt.yscale('log')` I get a message telling me `UserWarning: Data has no positive values, and therefore cannot be log-scaled.` I also cannot supply the values of `x` to `plt.plot` as the result of `log_10(x)` is so large and negative that the answer of `x**(log_10(x))` is simply `0`.

What might be the most straightforward way of plotting this data?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You can use

```
plt.yscale('symlog')
```

to set the scale to a symmetic log scale. This means that it will scale logarithmically to both sides of 0. Only using the negative part of the symlog scale would work just fine.

Comment: Here's a function to make range split into bins for symlog scale: https://gist.github.com/artoby/0bcf790cfebed5805fbbb6a9853fe5d5.

Answer (score 1):

Two alternatives to ImportanceOfBeingErnest's solution:

1. Plot `-log_10(x)` on a semilog y axis and set the y-label to display negative units
2. Plot `-log_10(-log_10(x))` on a linear scale

However, in all cases (including the solution proposed by ImportanceOfBeingErnest), the interpretation is not straightforward since you are displaying or calculating the log of a log.

Finally, in order to return the value for x, you need to calculate `10**(log_10(x))` not `x**(log_10(x))`